# Noise color whole screen when shutdown

Tags: 16.04, screen, noise

I have tried ubuntu 16.04, however its screen is noise of color when I shutdown.

I do not know why? Maybe my laptop has problem?

Comment: Does your laptop shutdown and powerdown as expected?
Not sure what you mean by noise of color... is this the so-called "splash screen"? If so, you can turn it on/off in Grub (look at installing Grub Customizer".

Comment: I do not know exactly what it is, however it look similar to this: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/36/e2/8c/36e28c8f601ca4794da51b4671bfa2f8.jpg.

Comment: ok, nice.. but does your laptop continue to shut down / power off  ?

Comment: the "splash screen" only occur a moment before laptop completely shutdow, and then everything is normal.

Comment: You could try to set Grub to `noquiet` and `nosplash`, which means you will see all the shutdown actions in the text terminal until the actual power off. Maybe you see anything suspicious there.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the appropriate graphics drivers for your system. It might help.

To install Intel Graphics Drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

To install AMD and ATI graphics, check out [this guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)